# VMWare: How to re-enter fullscreen VM after Alt+Tab?

Tags: virtual-machine, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware

I'm currently developing software on a linux virtual machine that runs inside VMWare Workstation Player 14, which in turn runs on a Windows 10 host. My preferred setup is to have the VM in fullscreen mode on one monitor and other host applications (like chrome) on the other monitors.

Switching from the VM to other host applications therefore requires me to first exit the VMWare fullscreen mode (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>) and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the desired window. That's something I can live with. What's more annoying is that after using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch back to the VM, the input is not propagated to the guest, so I have to click somewhere within the window using the mouse. Is there any setting or keyboard shortcut to achieve the same without using the mouse?

Comment: Since you run your VM in full screen all the time, you might be interested in running it through `vmware-kvm.exe` (which should be included with VMware Player).  Also see https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/03/whats-cool-vmware-kvm-utility.html

Comment: @jamesdlin nice hint, thanks! That's even closer to my desired experience and feels really lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're searching for: 
[image]

Comment: Ah yes perfect, thanks! I was mostly using the Player, which does not list this in the preferences. Opening the full Workstation and checking this setting did the trick (which now also works in the player).